# Error using "n-of" in NetLogo to select specific patches

Tags: if-statement, netlogo

I am new to NetLogo and I am working on a deforestation model, where farmers are my agents. They have a ID variable (**lotid-farmer**) that matches a ID in the patches (**lotid-patch**) that they own. Basically, farmers check how much money and labor they have to deforest some forest patches or abandon some of their agricultural patches (pcolor = red) in their farms. By the end of the latter procedure, farmers have a **"n-aband"** value calculated, which is the number of patched they will abandon (randomly) within their farms (pcolor = yellow). This is the piece of code that was supposed to do that:

```
ask farmers [
...
     if pcolor = red and lotid-patch = [ lotid-farmer ] of self [     ; Asks the farmer to randomly convert a # of the agricultural patches without maintenance to regrowth...
        ask n-of n-aband patches [ set pcolor yellow ]                ; ... among all agricultural patches own by the farmer
        ] 
...
```

However, when I run the code, farmers start "abandoning" patches that they **do not own**. I think that is because I am not setting up a proper "restriction" when I use "ask n-of n-aband patches" but I thought that that should be implicit in the "if" statement I have in the line above, no? I have also tried:

```
ask n-of n-aband patches with [ pcolor = red and lotid-patch = [ lotid-farmer ] of self ] [ set pcolor yellow ]
```

But I run into a error:

```
A patch can't access a turtle variable without specifying which turtle.
error while patch 390 414 running OF
  called by procedure CALCULATE-DEFORESTATION
  called by procedure GO
  called by Button 'Go'
```

Any suggestions on how to get this piece working? Thank you in advance.

Comment: as an aside, `[ lotid-farmer ] of self` reduces to just `lotid-farmer`. adding `of self` to NetLogo code never adds meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to consider only patches owned by the farmer.

```
ask farmers [
  let _id lotid-farmer
  let _candidates (patches with [lotid-patch = _id and pcolor = red])
  let _n-aband min (list n-aband count _candidates)
  ask n-of _n-aband _candidates [set pcolor yellow]
]
```

But ... don't work with ids.  Work with agents.  Let each patch have an owner,
which is a farmer or nobody.  Let each farmer maintain a list (or agentset)
of patches that it owns.

Comment: Thanks, Alan! Can anyone clarify if why do I need to use the "min" in "let _n-aband min (list n-aband count _candidates)" ? It seems to me that I would actually need to use "let _n-aband count _candidates" no?